# accessing information inside a jsp:include from the parent jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jquery, jspinclude

I'm trying to access form data that is filled out inside a jsp:included page from outside the page. I am using jquery and am open to using ajax. My code looks a little like this:

```
<form name=form1>
<jsp:include page="someFormData.jsp" />
//Other inputs out here in <% include %> files
<input type=button value=Submit onClick="return commonSubmit()"
</form>
```

I need to use the jsp:include style include because having everything on one page using 
<%include...%> was causing an exception due to my jsp being too large. Alls I need to do is be able to submit the form and include the data inside "someFormData.jsp"

Comment: `was causing an exception??` can you please show us?

Comment: jquery runs client side after the html page has been constructed.  At that point, there is no concept of jsp includes (or jsps in general).  You access the form field exactly as if the source was all one page.

Comment: Thanks Aurand...I don't know what was going on before but it's working now....much to my relief.